# Firebase Social media authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement social media authentication(FB and Google) with firebase.
First I used firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider) method which fails and throws auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment error.

Second approach is REST approach with firebase provided [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-sign-in-with-oauth-credential)

Has any one tried this before and what are the steps followed.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please indicate when you cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/NQobiV181hA

Comment: What's the environment you are running this from? There is a reason why you are getting this error. Is this a non-http environment? Do you have web storage disabled?

Comment: I am calling firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider) from the firebase cloud function deployed on firebase. Also the Client side is in Angular4 which calls the cloud function. Client side is deployed on a public accessible IP